# Opencart how to get module names?

Tags: opencart

In content_top.php:

```
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
<?php echo $module; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

As I understand it it loops all modules, where can I find which modules are used for the page, so I can edit the view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to walk through all the **installed** modules in Your administration (`Extenions` -> `Modules`) and those with modules for position `Content Top` are displaying within this template. I guess there is no easier way as all module settings are stored as serialized arrays (thus a string) within a `setting` DB table, thus searching for those with position `content_top` within a database would be pretty uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Administrator account, then go to Extensions, then Module. There are some modules that would display on your site, and some are backend stuff. The modules that would show on the site are those with Layout, Position, Status, and other attributes. To place it at certain positions, you need to select a value from Position. Layout selection would let you choose what page it should load the module.